# Why hovering over the main div shows the dropdown but the button does not?

Tags: html, css

I was trying to show the dropdown when the user hovers on the button but the dropdown only shows when i add the hover action to the parent container div. When i change the .dropdown:hover (the fourth selector - which changes the display to block) to .dropdownbtn:hover, it does not work, which in practical cases can cause problems. Why is it occuring. Does it have to do with the positioning?!

Here is the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/waleedrana777/yexhmbsq/1/

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: unset;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdownbtn {
  border: 0ch;
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(58, 199, 58);
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdownbtn {
  background-color: rgb(44, 151, 44);
}

.dropdown:hover ul.menu {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

ul>li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
  box-shadow: 10px 0px 95px 0.1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.472);
}

.menu>li {
  text-decoration: none;
  min-width: 105px;
  min-height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(58, 199, 180);
  border-bottom: black 1px;
}

.menu>li:hover,
.sub-menu>li:hover {
  background-color: rgb(47, 148, 134);
}

.sub-menu-toggle {
  position: relative;
}

.sub-menu {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  left: 125px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(58, 199, 180);
  box-shadow: 10px 0px 95px 0.1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.472);
}

.sub-menu>li {
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 50px;
  min-width: 105px;
}

.sub-menu-toggle:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content li::before {
  content: ;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropdownbtn">Dropdown button</button>

  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
      <li class="sub-menu-toggle">
        <a href='#'>Products</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li><a href='#'>Product 1</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>Product 2</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>Product 3</a></li>
          <li><a href='#'>Product 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What should i add to the html?

Comment: So it was not complete :)

Comment: Step 1: Validate the HTML. Step 2: Profit ;)

Comment: I'm really not sure what's your issue. So we added the missing closing `</a>`. What else?

Comment: If you change the fourth selector from .dropdown:hover to .dropdownbtn:hover, it does not work!

Answer (score 2):

This does appear to be due to positioning. You mentioned that .dropdown:hover works but changing it to the following does not:

```
.dropdownbtn:hover ul.menu {   
    display: block;
 }
```

This is because the selector declared here is looking for a descendant  element with class `menu` inside of `.dropdownbtn` which does not exist.

Using `.dropdown:hover` works because the `ul.menu` element is a descendant of the `div.dropdown` element, and not the `button.dropdownbtn` element.

Comment: So what would be the case where i have to show the dropdown when mouse hovers on the ```.dropdownbtn ``` instead of the ```.dropdown```. Also you are saying that the element which is selected on hover must be a descendant element of the element being hovered?

Comment: I think you can put the hover wherever you want, but the div containing the button has to be a block one way or another.

Comment: I don't think it is feasible to achieve your desired functionality using only CSS and HTML. You could potentially wrap the `.dropdownbtn` and the `.dropdown-content` elements in a span within the div, but this results in the same functionality. If you absolutely need to bind showing the drop down menu when only hovering the button, you may need to use JavaScript or some framework.